# Find $f$ for which $f(x)f'(x)=1$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Find an example for which $f(x)f'(x)=1$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

I need to find an example for which $f(x)f'(x)=1$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. I hope you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: I have no idea how to start

Comment: $$f(x)\ df(x)=dx$$
Integrating we get 
$$\dfrac{f^2(x)}2=x+c$$

Answer (score 3):

Let $y = f(x)$. Then we need $y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx} = 1$ i.e.
$$y dy = dx$$Now integrate both sides
$$\int y dy = \int dx \Rightarrow \frac{y^2}{2} = x+c\Rightarrow y = \pm \sqrt{2(x+c)}$$ 
where $c\in \mathbb{R}$.

However this is not defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ since $2(x+c)$ can be negative.

Comment: I think that this is not true as it is not defined for $x\leq 0$. The OP explicitly asks for a solution which is defined for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(x)f'(x) = 1$, so is $(f^2)'(x) = 2$. Thus, $f^2(x)= 2x + C$.

This, however, is a contradiction because for any $C\in\mathbb{R}$, there exits an $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $2x + C <0$. But note that $f^2(x) \geq 0$.